# imageView.setImageBitmap is not working in android

Tags: android, android-layout

solved by Emil thx
I have following in my main

```
package com.example.surfacetest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.hero_frame);
        img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.chen_gong));

    }

}
`
```

in the xml file I have

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hero1"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5.33dp"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hero2"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5.33dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hero1"
    />
```

Is there anything that I am missing, I worked on this question for the past two days and can't find any solution on internet or I am missing it. Help please.

Comment: Are you getting an Exception? I suspect a NullPointerException or ClassCastException. "Not working" is very vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.hero_frame);
```

You need to pass the ID of the ImageView you want to find, you are probably getting a `NullPointerException` at the moment, because `img` can not be found, try something like this:

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hero1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.chen_gong);
```

or directly from the xml layout by adding the line to your `ImageView` tag :

```
android:src="@drawable/chen_gong"
```